# deleting the parent div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery scripts aimed at deleting the parent div. However, the delete button doesn't appear as a button and won't delete the parent div. I am using jQuery Mobile.

Here is the jquery:

```
 $(".delete_content").click(function() { 
    $(this).closest(".content_container").remove();   
   });
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class='content_container'>
      <a class='delete_content' data-role='button' data-icon='delete' data-inline='true' data-iconpos='right'>
            Delete
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean doesnt appear as a button? Does it show as an html link?

Comment: The code seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/u6KjW/

Comment: a jquery button in jquery mobile has a default looking style. It doesn't show up as a button or even a link, just black letters. I was told in a prior question that jfiddle doesn't work for jquery mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".delete_content").click(function() { 
    $(this).parents(".content_container").remove();   
});
```

You need to use `.parents` and not `.closest`

Comment: Seriously, is there a `.parents` in jQuery?

Comment: Yep, it goes all the way up the tree @PraveenKumar :-)